# Dired: Search by one letter

Tags: dired

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Dired+, Dired-K

Here my test folder:

[image: dired]

If I want to go folder **test2** I press `M-x` and then `C-s (I-search)`.
Here result:

[image: search]

OK. It's work.

But... I think it's slow.
It would be good if I can go to folder/file only by one letter.
E.g. If I press **s** then I go to file **searchview.png**. If I quickly press **st** then go to file **step1.png**. And so on.

Is it possible in Emacs?

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/winterTTr/ace-jump-mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "*I press **`M-x`** and then `C-s`*". That can't be right. There is no reason to use `M-x` here. Just use `C-s`.

`C-s s` gives you what you want - it moves to file `searchview.png`. But if you want to be sure to search only file names (none of the other text in the buffer, then use **`M-s f C-s`**, which is bound to command `dired-isearch-filenames`.

If you want to use only a single key to initiate such a search, bind `dired-isearch-filenames` to an unused single key. For example:

```
(define-key dired-mode-map (kbd "<f12>") 'dired-isearch-filenames)
```

Then **`<f12> s`** takes you directly to file `searchview.png` and `<f12> st` takes you to file `step1.png`.

If you don't like using a function key, such as `<f12>`, and if there is some other single key available or whose current binding you don't care about, then bind that key.  For example, if you never use `a`, which is bound by default to `dired-find-alternate-file`, then bind `a` to `dired-isearch-filenames` instead. Then you can just use `a s` to get where you want.

If you want to be sure to match your search pattern only at the beginning of a file name (not in the middle) then start the pattern with a space char.

You can also use regexp matching, with **`M-s f C-M-s`** (command `dired-isearch-filenames-regexp`).